# How to protect from teamviewer attacks

Tags: teamviewer, dashlane

My teamviewer account was hacked, morning I get up and see the mouse is moving on the screen, right away I knew something is wrong, and close the teamviewer connection. Looked at the logs and found they have moved over some files like browerpassviewer to the desktop but could not find anything not sure if its hidden or may be they deleted it as I don't store any passwords in the browser.

I did have dashlane which allows me to automatically log into sites, so they were able to get to my paypal account and move money. i have called paypal and they are looking into it.

I have activated two step authentication for paypal and teamviewer. Is there anything else that I need to do to protect myself and the two step is also not that secure.

Comment: its odd you were targeted? sounds like someone you might have known?

Comment: Is your teamviewer version up to date ?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: you should reinstall your OS and change the passwords available via Dashlane (or otherwise saved on your computer)**

Sorry to give you the boilerplate answer to the "I was hacked, now what?" question but this is really the only solution to ensure that you are secure.

Going the reverse-engineering-the-attack path is complicated and requires forensics knowledge, luck and you never know whether you fixed all the issues.

It is not clear how you were attacked:

- maybe your Teamviewer password was weak and they guessed it: have a better password and two-factor authentication
- maybe Teamviewer had a vulnerability: use the latest version
- maybe something else had a vulnerability: update all your components (OS + applications)
- maybe you unwillingly installed a keylogger: avoid clicking unknown links, starting unknown software, yada yada yada

> (...) the two step is also not that secure.

It is very secure for the intended use: protect your account from being accessed by a login/password which may leak.

Comment: just stating the (not always so) obvious: `or otherwise saved on your computer` includes passwords saved by browsers, if the used browser(s) will show you your passwords if asked - i.e. Firefox does that when no master-password is set (since I don't use any other browser that saves passwords, I cannot comment on the likes of Chrome and Edge).